# Why this function acts like loop when it executed couple times

Tags: javascript

Why is this function acts like loop when it executed couple times did this counter stored in the add function or not

```js
let counter = 0;

function add() {
  return counter++;
}

console.log(add());
console.log(add());
console.log(add());
console.log(add());
```

if it increments I don't understand its difference from this while loop

```
let i = 0;
while(i <= 3){
  console.log(i)
  i++;
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Increment

Comment: Try changing the loop to a large number like `1000` . Now there is a huge difference to 1000 lines of code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

that **add()** function if executed couple time it will act like loop but not real loop because this doesn't need condition to stop iterating so this is the function not the loop
and even if it iterates it take no condition

Comment: It acts nothing like a loop. It's just incrementing a variable - `x++` isn't "looping" over anything.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether I understand your question correctly but both of these code examples should give the same output.

Your `add` function uses the counter variable that is declared outside of it. That means each time your function is called from your `console.log()` lines, it will add 1 to the counter.
Since you don't reset the counter within your function, it will use the already stored value which would be 1 after the first `console.log()` statement, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

The  `counter`, defined by let initially is in the global scope which is changed by your function.
Check out https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_let.asp for mor details!